# python POST requests with file + data

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

Iam trying to upload a picture and a information over an API that requires to be send as a form. I tried to use the "files" option, that requests provides with no success. It gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The line of code I tried is:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=header, files = {'imageFile' :    open('test_pic/1.jpg'), 'ticket' : ticket}, verify=False)
```

Cheers Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to try:

1. If you're using Windows make sure to add a `b` to the file permissions for `open`:

   ```
   open('filename', 'rb')
   ```

   This will make sure that the file is read as a binary which otherwise can cause some errors
2. When sending multiple files, you need to pass in a list of tuples, and not a dictionary:

   ```
   >>> multiple_files = [('images', ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
                 ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))]
   >>> r = requests.post(url, files=multiple_files)
   ```

   This is according to the [online documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files).

Answer (score 2):

```
files = {'imageFile' :    open('test_pic/1.jpg'), 'ticket' : ticket}
```

Is the `ticket` of type `int`? I just got the same problem, the value in files must be `str` or `bytes` or `bytearray` or a file object(this will cause a read action)，see details in requests's models.py(function `_encode_files()`)